# Bind value in checkbox silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0

I have 3 Checkbox in xaml file.Name sit,stand,sleep.
Extype having the following values 1,2,3

```
CheckBox Content="Sit" Margin="127,89,212,136" IsChecked="{Binding Extype}" RenderTransformOrigin="1.817,-1.029"/>

CheckBox Content="Stand" Margin="127,89,212,136" IsChecked="{Binding Extype}" RenderTransformOrigin="1.817,-1.029"/>

CheckBox Content="Sleep" Margin="127,89,212,136" IsChecked="{Binding Extype}" RenderTransformOrigin="1.817,-1.029"/>
```

If the Extype value is **one** means I need to select Sit check box.

If the Extype value is **two** means I need to select stand check box.

If the Extype value is **three** means I need to select both check boxes.

How can I do this?

Comment: only one converter is required and pass the parameter to the converter to identify the checkbox please check this [link](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)

Comment: Write 10 converters.

Comment: Don't use CheckBoxes, use RadioButtons.

Comment: Write 100 converters. Just to be safe. But follow the previous advice.

Comment: ...and then you write a converter.

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="Sit" IsChecked="{Binding IsSit, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False"/>
<CheckBox Content="Stand" IsChecked="{Binding IsStand, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False"/>
<CheckBox Content="Sleep" IsChecked="{Binding IsSleep, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public bool IsSit
{
    get
    {
        return ExtType == 1 || ExtType == 3;
    }
}

public bool IsStand
{
    get
    {
        return ExtType == 2 || ExtType == 3;
    }
}

private int _extType;
public int ExtType
{
    get
    {
        return _extType;
    }

    set
    {
        _extType = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsSit");
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsStand");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing some code here. Where is `IsStand` and `IsSleep`? Not to mention that this will not work as these properties are **read-only**. You'll need to add **setters**.

Comment: @MikeEason If you read the question, it only mentions setting the IsChecked on Sit and Stand. It also only mentions setting the IsChecked based on the ExtType value, not from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ValueConverter with a parameter. Use the same ValueConverter in each checkbox but change the parameter value.

```
<CheckBox Content="Sit" IsChecked="{Binding Extype, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}, ConverterParameter=Sit}" />
<CheckBox Content="Standup" IsChecked="{Binding Extype, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}, ConverterParameter=Standup}" />
```

Here an example of a ValueConverter with parameters:
http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

(Remember to add your ValueConverter as a Resource.)

And then put your business logic code inside the ValueConverter or even better, call a function in your Business Layer.